# Pulling python module up into package namespace

Tags: python, namespaces

If I have a directory structure like this:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    functions.py      #contains do()
    classes.py        #contains class A()
```

And I want to be able to call

```
import package as p
```

How do I make the contents of `functions`, `classes`, accessible as:

```
p.do()
p.A()
```

**in stead of:**

```
p.functions.do()
p.classes.A()
```

The subdivision in files is only there for convenience (allowing easier collaboration), but I'd prefer to have all the contents in the same namespace.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You *could* do this in `__init__.py` (because that's what you import when you `import package`):

```
from package.functions import *
from package.classes import *
```

However, [`import *` is nearly always a bad idea](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import) and this isn't one of the exceptions. Instead, many packages explicitly import a limited set of commonly-used names - say,

```
from package.functions import do
from package.classes import A
```

This too allows accessing `do` or `A` directly, but it's not nearly as prone to name collisions and the other problems that come from `import *`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I didn't need to `import *`, selecting the functions worked fine. I didn't know doing this (`from B import B`) would put `B` into the `package` namespace as `package.B`. Though it's kind of obvious now.